# Typing 'Ctrl' in webstorm 'Enter Keyboard Shortcut' does not work

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm trying to configure some keymaps in Webstorm, but when I hit Ctrl or Shift in the 'Enter Keyboard Shortcut' dialog it does not have any effect. I'm using Ubuntu and Webstorm 10.

Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: It almost certainly expects a real keyboard shortcut, like Ctrl and A pressed together. Not just Ctrl. Or Shift Alt C and not just shift.

Comment: That's correct: you do not type actual shortcut -- you just press whole combo while focus is in that field.

Comment: Thanks, that was the case :-D